# Blazor page does not work when the url is changed manually

Tags: blazor

When I manually change the Url in a specific route does not work, as you can see in the image below.

- If I change from `https://localhost:7065/medicationcontrol` to `https://localhost:7065/medicationcontrol/add` it does not work.
- But if I switch to `https://localhost:7065/medicationcontrol` it works.

Anyway, if the URL `https://localhost:7065/medicationcontrol/add` is invoked in the code, it also works. I can't understand what is happening.

[image]

The route of this page, in the *add.razor* page is:

```
@page "/medicationcontrol/add"
```

My Program.cs of my server application I use:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Blazor WASM application, when you manually change the Url you're forcing an external navigation, that is, Blazor's router can't intercept and process it, so the browser is producing a request to the backend with the url you've written. Then, depending on how the backend is configured this could cause an error response (NotFound, BadRequest, ...) or may cause the reload of the entire client application if you have a default endpoint mapped:

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

in Program.cs

If this fallback is set, when the client application reloads, Blazor tries to load the component that matches the url. That's very inefficient and you should avoit it.

If this fallback is missing then the backend will try to match the requested url (https://localhost:7065/medicationcontrol/add) in the API and, if doesn't match any controller action, it will return a 404 NotFound response, that is what your image above is showing.

Comment: thank for your explanation. I really use the `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); `. But if I remove this line my app does not work, doesn't open.

I updated my question